# How to fix a Comparator for use in TreeSet

Tags: java, collections, set, logic, treeset

I have a TreeSet with a custom comparator, but the remove() operation isn't working.
Here is the code:

```
new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Tile>(){
            public int compare(Tile o1, Tile o2){
                if(o1 == o2){
                    return 0;
                }
                if(o1.getValue() > o2.getValue()){
                    return 1;
                }
                return -1;
            }
        });
```

I think, with this comparator a duplicate is defined as o1 == o2, and de order is ascending based on getValue(). But something is wrong.. what?

Answer (score 3):

> `o1 == o2`

This is comparing object references, not the value. You aren't covering the case where the values are equal. Assuming the call to `getValue()` isn't expensive, I usually skip the object refrence equality check to make my code a bit simpler.

```
public int compare(Tile o1, Tile o2){
    if(o1.getValue() == o2.getValue()){
         return 0;
    }
    if(o1.getValue() > o2.getValue()){
         return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Or, more simply:

```
public int compare(Tile o1, Tile o2){
    return o1.getValue() - o2.getValue();
}
```

Comment: i know what i'm checking with == . But if o1.getValue() equals the value of o2, it isn't a duplicate in my case. duplicates are only objects which are the same, so o1 == o2. I want to have different objects in my set, with the same value, as long they aren't o1 == o2

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written `compare` doesn't meet the contract for that method. One of the conditions you must meet is:

```
sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y
```

But your `compare`  method doesn't satisfy this condition because if you have two `Tile`s `x` and `y` satisfying `x != y` and `x.getValue() == y.getValue()` then `compare(x, y)` and `compare(y, x)` are both `-1`.

If you break the contract for `compare`, you get unpredictable results,

If you want two instances of `Tile` to only be considered duplicates if they have the same identity, then it is difficult to see how you could possibly meet the above condition, so a this rules out using a `TreeSet`. Instead you could use a `HashSet` where you don't override `equals` or `hashCode` for the class `Tile`. If you are not in control of the class `Tile`, and `equals` and `hashCode` are already overridden then you could use the `keySet` view of an `IdentityHashMap` or Guava's `newIdentityHashSet()`. Unfortunately these solutions don't keep the collection sorted.

If you need the collection to be sorted based on the values returned by `getValue()` and you only want to remove duplicates when the instances are identically equal, I don't think there's any sensible way of doing this. You could use an `ArrayList` which you keep sorted using `Collections.sort` (in combination with the comparator returning `Double.compare(o1.getValue(), o2.getValue());`). Whenever you need to remove duplicates you could do something like this

```
Map<Tile, Void> map = new IdentityHashMap<>();
for (Tile tile : list)
    map.put(tile, null);
list = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
```

Comment: really? there isn't any way to achieve this with a sorted set?... but yes, this is exactly my problem...

Comment: @T_01 I am 99% sure that it is impossible to write a legal `compare` method where `compare(a, b)` only equals `0` if `a == b`. How could you order two instances where all fields are equal but instances are not identical? There's no way to tell whether the answer should be 1 or -1.

Comment: hmm. what if i just order them by a field like creationTime in nano seconds? There shouldnt be dublicates. But how could i implement this?

Comment: maybe something like:
if(o1.getValue() > o2.getValue(){
   return 1;
}
else if(o1.getValue() < o2.getValue()){
   return 1;
}
else {
  if(o1.getCreationTime() > o2.getCreationTime()){
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return -1;
  }
}

Comment: but when the compare method should return 0 then?

Comment: @T_O1 start `if (o1 == o2) return 0`. Then do what you said. Strictly speaking it doesn't work because objects can be created so quickly that `System.nanoTime` can return the same thing twice. A safer approach would be to use `random.nextLong`. Again, that strictly speaking doesn't work either as two random `long` values can be equal, but it's just very unlikely. There's no satisfactory solution to this,

Comment: @T_01 I've just realised I'm being really dumb. You don't want a random `long` you just want to use a variable `static long counter` that is incremented every time you instantiate. It still doesn't work but it's ok as long as you don't instantiate more than 2^64 objects

Comment: yes i also thought about this solution. why "it still doesn't work" ?

Comment: When I say "it still doesn't work" I mean it does work as long as you don't create more than 2^64 objects. It effectively works. I don't know who downvoted but I just upvoted it.

Comment: okay, sorry, my english is'nt so good :) i'll try this solution.